# Vertically and Center Align Text

Tags: html, css

I have a `h1` within the `body` and want to vertically align and center align this text.

I know I can use the `position: absolute;` and then `margin-top: "HALF OF HEIGHT";` but this h1 changes on refresh and has different widths. The height is always the same so I can vertically align it fine but it's center aligning it. I can't use `text-align: center;` becuase the h1 is positioned absolute so it won't work.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't horizontally center it using `position: absolute` for varying text widths. What's the problem with removing that?

Comment: Because I used `position: absolute` to vertically align it. The height is 60px but the width is unknown. At the moment I have it as `position: absolute; height: 60px; top: 50%; margin-top: -30px;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the element doesn't have a background, you could do this to horizontally center an element with absolute positioning:

```
.your-element {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}​
```

A working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VSySg/

Comment: Ah yes, `width: 100%`! Totally forgot about that. Thanks! It worked perfectly, I'll accept your answer in a few minutes when it allows me too. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

**Depending** on the rest of your layout, this may work:

```
h1 {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: /* height of container */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xC3vn/

Comment: I needed to add `width: 100%;` for `text-align: center;` to work. Works fine now, thanks!